# using sessionAsSigner and currentSession in the same thread

Tags: xpages

I just came to a strange JAVA problem that i cant fix.

I call a JAVA bean to retrieve some values from a view.
To do that i call a JAVA class to do the Lookup.

The lookup is called twice. Once with the currentUser id and after that with SessionAsSigner to retrieve documents the currentUser cant read because of reader fields.

Here is my observation: It seems that the first time you retrieve a session(either the asSigner or currentSession) this session will be then the only session you can use in this thread. Once you call the other method it will still be either the currentSession or the asSigner session.

I tried to recylce the session, write 2 beans that carry only the session, write two JAVA classes that each host different sessions the result is always the same. The first session initialized is the only session you can get. To retrieve the session i used already the ExtLib class, DomUtils and VariableResolver but it seems to be always the same issue regardless how i get the sessions.

Here is a small example and the result i get:

Example 1:

```
Session s=Util.getCurrentSession()
Vector<String>=result=Util.lookup(s,view,key)
//result is empty because user cant read the documents -OK
Session s=Util.getSessionasSigner()
Vector<String>=result=Util.lookup(s,view,key)
//result is empty although Signer can read document -NOK
```

Example 2

```
 Session s=Util.getSessionasSigner()
 Vector<String>=result=Util.lookup(s,view,key)
 //result returns the documents -OK
 Session s=Util.getCurrentSession()
 Vector<String>=result=Util.lookup(s,view,key)
 //result again returns the documents allthough the user shouldnt be able to read it -NOK
```

So whatever i do the second call is always wrong because of that issue.
Has anybody any idea what i can do about it.

Comment: I smell some cache issue inside that lookup method.

Comment: No its not a caching issue. Within the loookup method i do print  the effectiveusername and it prints always the same name while i expect that the username should be anonymous for currentuser and myself(the developer) with assigner

Answer (score 4):

There are a few possible options here, depending on what your util method is doing.

One is outlined in this question [SessionAsSigner - database object conflicts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25845795/sessionassigner-database-object-conflicts).

Another may relate to how you are getting the relevant database? `getCurrentDatabase()` cannot be used with `sessionAsSigner` after getting another session. You need to use getDatabase() the second time.

For getting sessionAsSigner, I would recommend using `ExtLibUtil.getCurrentSessionAsSigner()`. There's no point reinventing the wheel.

Also, don't recycle `session`. Recycling any Domino object recycles all descendants. So you're basically recycling any Domino references created but not released elsewhere in the request cycle. It's likely to have some strange impacts which could be hard to pin down. The only time to recycle anything outside a loop is as outlined in Sven's answer to the first question linked.

Comment: I used Extlib and also getDatabase but it doesnt work. The first session that comes back from the util class willl be the only session you can use

Answer (score 2):

Thanks Paul i found it. You brought me into the right direction.

Allthough i am using getDatabase as a method i had to recycle the database object after i have used. It looks like without the recycle it kind of still keeps the session to the database and i cant get a sessionAsSigner session.

After i have recycled the database object i was then able to get the sessionAsSigner session and it returned the correct documents.